# Не запускается приложение Jetbrains Toolbox в Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, jetbrains

Скачал приложение Toolbox от Jetbrains

[image: Меню Dash]

При запуске ругается

> Invalid url: '/home/bi/Downloads/BioPerl-1.6.0/jetbrains-toolbox-1.1.2143/jetbrains-toolbox' given, exiting
>
> No ':' in the uri

[image: Диалоговое окно с ошибкой]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Мне помогла перезагрузка компа два раза)

Comment: Почему два? почему не три или семь? или четные - работает, нечетные - вылетает ошибка? А в это время вы танцевали с бубном? Это важно! А может печеньку ели с чаем. Не упускайте важных деталей.

Comment: Просто после первой перезагрузки я не проверял запуск Toolbox, а  обновлял систему. А потом он сам..